# Unparseable date JsonDeserializer Gson Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I guess all my Gson DateDeserializer setup is fine but it throws an error saying `Unparseable date` Thank in Advance.

```
private Gson getGson() {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        return builder.create();
    }
```

DateDeserializer:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import timber.log.Timber;

public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final String TAG = "DateDeserializer";
    private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[]{
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
            "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a",// Aug 29, 2016 09:11:08 AM
            "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss",//Aug 29, 2016 16:11:08
    };

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {

            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Timber.d(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
    }



}
```

Logcat:

```
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-19T13:27:58+05:30" (at offset 19)
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27T06:32:00+00:00" (at offset 19)
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27T06:32:00+00:00" (at offset 19)
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27 06:32:00+00:00" (at offset 10)
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27 06:32:00+00:00" (at offset 10)
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27 06:32:00+00:00" (at offset 0)
D/DateDeserializer: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27 06:32:00+00:00" (at offset 0)
W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-10-27 06:32:00+00:00". Supported formats: [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a, MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss]
```

Comment: you need a pattern for `2016-10-27 06:32:00+00:00` as well. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ` should do it

Comment: Thanks, It worked but what is the use of 'T' why is this "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" not working.

Comment: if you look close to the dates you are trying to parse, you will notice that some of them have `T` between date and time, if it that what you mean

Answer (score 0):

this method is throwing exception even if no exception is occurred. this method should be like this:

```
@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {

        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Timber.d(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

now for which. format will be matched, that date will be returned. if doesn't match with any format, then null will be returned.

Comment: Thank, but i want it to throw an exception when none of the date formats are parsable. any way this is not my question.

Comment: then there is problem with date format, you can check the examples of the following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html